# Slope of $x$-$t²$ curve (displacement vs time squared)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I know that slope of $x$ vs $t^2$ curve gives $\frac{a}{2}$. How do I prove it?

This is what I did :

$x = ut + \frac{at^2}{2}$

$x = \frac{at^2}{2}$    (for $u=0$)

$\frac{dx}{dt^2} = \frac{a}{2}$

But! Here I assumed that initial velocity is zero. But what if it is non-zero? I know that slope would still be $\frac{a}{2}$, but how do I prove it?

Comment: Just use the frame of reference in which u *is* zero...

Comment: That's interesting. Doesn't it make any difference? I mean, choosing a different frame for which $u$ is zero?

Comment: Your initial premise is *only* correct for a frame in which u - 0.  And changes in velocity (accelerations) are independent of any constant velocity frame choice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking what you ask at face value, we have

\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt^2}
x
&=
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt^2}
\left(
\frac12 at^2 + ut
\right)
\\
&=
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt^2}
\left(
\frac12 at^2 + u\left(t^2\right)^{1/2}
\right)
\\ &=
\frac 12 a + \frac12 u \left(t^2\right)^{-1/2}
\\&= \frac12 \left(a + \frac ut\right)
\end{align}

So the slope *asyptotically* approaches $a/2$ as you get far enough away from $t=0$ that the initial velocity is ignorable.  But the slope never is actually *equal* to $a/2$.  It's illustrative for you to open your favorite plotting program and compare the well-behaved parabolae of $x=\frac12 at^2 + ut + x_0$ as a function of $t$ to the very different shape they assume as a function of $t^2$.

If you're actually fitting data, I advise [polynomial regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression) in $x$ versus $t$, in which $a/2$, $u$, and $x_0$ enter as first-order parameters.
What you're doing is linear regression on $x$ versus $t^2$, which is a superior analytical technique if your computational tools are a straightedge and a pencil.
Even spreadsheet programs support polynomial regression these days.

Answer (score 0):

If $u=0$ then a graph of $s$ against $t$ will be a straight line through the origin  of gradient $\frac a 2$.
You are comparing $s=\frac 12a \, t^2 +0 $ with the general equation of a straight line $y=mx+c$.

If there is an initial velocity then to linerise the graph write the equation as $\frac s t = \frac 12a\,t + u$ and compare it with $y=mx+c$.

Thus a graph of $\frac s t$ against $t$ should be a straight line of gradient $\frac 12 a$ and intercept on the $\frac st$ axis of $u$.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. It makes sense. But isn't 's/t vs x' a different curve? Compared to 's vs t²' curve? Just wondering. Because here we are specifically talking about 's vs t²' curve

Comment: @πtimese If there is an initial velocity a graph of $s$ against $t^2$ will not be a straight line.

Comment: Always treat with suspicion any question that starts; "I (We all,,,) know that.....".